# Unable to delete entry in Firebase database using remove

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to remove an entry from my Firebase database, but am not able to delete it.

**Here's my database structure**:

[image]

**Here's what I've tried**:

```
let subRefs = firebase.database().ref('subscriptions/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    let objs = snapshot.val();
    for (let key in objs){
    if (objs[key].uid == memberId){
        console.log('found'); // I see this in the console 
        //remove the subscription
        let ref = firebase.database().ref('subscription/' + userId + '/' + key);
        ref.remove().then(function() {
            console.log("Remove succeeded");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Remove failed");
        });
      }
    }
 });
```

I've also tried the following approach as suggested [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data) in the docs, but that didn't work either.

```
let update = {};
update['subscription/' + userId + '/' + key] = null;
firebase.database().ref().update(update).then(function(){
    console.log('remove success');
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log('remove failed');
});
```

In both cases, I see the "remove success" log, but when I check the database, it's not actually deleted.

Comment: You have a typo: `'subscription/'`. Note the missing `s`.

Comment: omg thank you @cartant!